# over regular Languages L and D(L)

Tags: regular-language, dfa, nfa

Suppose you have an operation D defined as D(L) = {nm| n,m ∈ L} where L is the language over SIGMA. If L is regular and D(L) should be also regular.

I am trying to prove this, by doing:

THE DEFINITION OF REGULAR LANGUAGES:  A LANGUAGE L⊆Σ* IS REGULAR IF THERE IS A DFA M SUCH THAT L = L(M).
so we know that since L is regular there is a DFA A = (Q, Σ, δ, q0, F), consisting of:

1. a finite set of states (Q)
2. a finite set of input called the alphabet (Σ)
3. a transition function (δ : Q × Σ → Q)
4. a start state (q0)
5. accept state (F ⊆ Q)

that accepts L. So there should be a NFA L' = (Σ, Γ, S, σ0, δ, w):

- Σ is the input alphabet (a finite non-empty set of symbols).
- Γ is the output alphabet (a finite, non-empty set of symbols).
- S is a finite, non-empty set of states
- σ0 is the initial state
- δ is the state-transition function
- w is the output function.

is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is confusing to me. I am writing hint to proof that language D: = { nm | n, m ∈ L}  is regular if language L is a regular.

Hint: D is concatenation (cartesian product) of two regular languages L<sub>n</sub> and L<sub>m</sub>, where L<sub>n</sub> = L<sub>m</sub> = L — hance D is also a regular language. check [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Formal_definition).

Draw DFA,

1. Draw, M(L<sub>n</sub>) a DFA for L<sub>a</sub> with starting state  Q<sub>n0</sub> and F<sub>n</sub> is set of final states.
2. Draw, M(L<sub>m</sub>) a DFA for L<sub>m</sub> with starting state  Q<sub>m0</sub> and F<sub>m</sub> is set of final states.
    <sub>both DFAs are same except different name of states.</sub>
3. Add null transitions from each final state in F<sub>**n**</sub> to start state Q<sub>**m**0</sub>. — this is NFA.
4. Remove null transitions one by one — now the resultant DFA accepts language D.

Note: your teacher will not give you full marks if you don't explains how it accepts exactly  language D. You have to write fifth point - because aftr consuming a n ∈ L you reaches to one of the final state in F<sub>**n**</sub>, then without consuming any symbol you shifts to start state of DFA M(L<sub>m</sub>) then after processing any m ∈ L you reaches to a final state in F<sub>**n**</sub> chance this proofs that D is a regular language. Pick a good book so learn how to formally write these steps.

Write regular expression:

1. Suppose N regular expression for L<sub>n</sub>
2. Suppose M regular expression for L<sub>m</sub>
3. then NM would be regular expression for D

Again explain how NM accepts D.